# A Java preparedStatement with a setBigDecimal parameter raises ORA-03115

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement

The problem is: I'm setting a preparedStatement for a query in a table with this fields (among others):

```
TABLE1_RSPN NUMBER(8,0)
TABLE1_AFDV NUMBER(8,0)
TABLE1_VALUE    NUMBER(17,2)
TABLE1_NOTE VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
TABLE1_USR  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
```

...

Trying to get some info into my Java app, I set a preparedStatement which raises the Oracle exception *ORA-03115 unsupported network datatype or representation.*

The relevant Java code is this:

```
sentSQL = "SELECT TABLE1.*, TABLE2.CIAS FROM TABLE1, TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1_RSPN = ?" +
" AND TABLE2_AFDV = TABLE1_AFDV";
ps = con.prepareStatement(sentSQL);
ps.setBigDecimal(1, dto.getCodResponsability());
rs = ps.executeQuery(sentSQL);
```

CodResponsability is BigDecimal. I've also tried with Double and Long, with no joy.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is probably wrong:

```
rs = ps.executeQuery(sentSQL);
```

This actually calls [Statement's executeQuery](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) and ignores the variables you've bound.

It should be

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you! No TV and no beer makes Alfabravo go crazy... and forget. :)